# how to make element rotate on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im making an accordion and wonder how to make an arrow (lets suppose its an arrow svg icon) rotate 180deg once an accordion element is clicked and expanded in Vanilla JS?

Currently it only rotates the first element from the dom found that is matching my selected tag, because of `querySelector` and not `querySelectorAll`. How to use `querySelectorAll` properly in this case so not all of them get rotated?

```js
document.querySelectorAll("details").forEach((accordion) => {
    accordion.addEventListener("click", () => {
      document.querySelectorAll("details").forEach((event) => {
        document.querySelector("details span").classList.add("active");
        if (accordion !== event) {
          event.removeAttribute("open");
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

```css
summary{ 
  list-style: none 
}

details{
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: lightblue;

 }

details summary{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

details:nth-child(even){
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

p{
  padding-top: 0.3rem;
}

.active{
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

span{
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <details>
    <summary>    
      <h3>item1</h3> 
      <span>arrow</span> </summary>
    <p>desc1</p>
  </details>
  <details>
    <summary>
      <h3>item2</h3> 
      <span>arrow</span> 
    </summary> 
    <p>desc2</p>
  </details>
  <details>
    <summary> 
      <h3>item3</h3> 
      <span>arrow</span> 
    </summary>
    <p>desc3</p>
  </details>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your accordion is clicked you are running a loop through all the accordions and performing actions. But you only need to look at the `span` which is child of the clicked accordion.

As identified, this statement selects only the first `span` from first `details` :  `document.querySelector("details span").classList.add("active");`.

You can use `this`. `this` inside eventlistener callbacks always give the element on which event is attached. (You cannot use arrow functions with `this`). That is why I have converted them to non arrow functions.

I am following the same logic as yours but after removing from all the accordions, I am modifying the properties of the children of the current accordion. Have a look:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("details").forEach((accordion) => {
    accordion.addEventListener("click", function () {
      document.querySelectorAll("details").forEach(function (elem) {
          elem.removeAttribute("open");
          elem.querySelector("span").classList.remove("active");
        }); this.querySelector("span").classList.add("active");

    });
  });
```

```css
summary{ 
  list-style: none 
}

details{
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: lightblue;

 }

details summary{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

details:nth-child(even){
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

p{
  padding-top: 0.3rem;
}

.active{
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

span{
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <details>
    <summary>    
      <h3>item1</h3> 
      <span>arrow</span> </summary>
    <p>desc1</p>
  </details>
  <details>
    <summary>
      <h3>item2</h3> 
      <span>arrow</span> 
    </summary> 
    <p>desc2</p>
  </details>
  <details>
    <summary> 
      <h3>item3</h3> 
      <span>arrow</span> 
    </summary>
    <p>desc3</p>
  </details>
</div>
```

Comment: May i ask u how this works? I previously had an `if` check that ensured to close the item that was already opened and was not the item i was clicking next. Now we dont have that `if` check and we remove an attribute and a class. So shouldnt it remove the attribute and a class the same time we click on a certain element? So basically nothing happens, because we open and remove open at the same time? 

But i also understand it the way that the attribute and a class get added only after they are removed from the previous element because line code with `this` is the last one in the function.

Comment: Does the second part i wrote is correct? @Tushar Shahi

Answer (score 0):

You are making use of event listeners but not the actual event data. Once your event listener is triggered the first parameter will contain all the data you need. In your case it would be as simple as adding a parameter to your event listener

```js
accordion.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    //...
}
```

I used 'e' as name but it could be 'event' or anything you find most readable. Then you can use e like it's the exact element you're targeting, for example:

```js
e.target.classlist.toggle("active");
```

you can even target it's parent/child elements by doing

```js
e.target.parentElement.classlist.toggle("active");

e.target.querySelector("span")
```

Putting the query selector on the target narrows down where it's looking all the way down to your details element which I think is exactly what you want here. My final solution would be

```js
document.querySelectorAll("details").forEach((accordion) => {
    accordion.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        document.querySelectorAll("detail").forEach((element) => {
            element.open = false
            element.querySelector("span").classList.remove("active");
        });
        e.target.open = true;
        e.target.querySelector("span").classList.add("active");
      });
    });
  })
```